# Chance encoding of many files

Tags: csv, encoding, utf-8

I have more than 500 CSV files, some of them with utf-8 encoding anda others with ascii encoding.
Also, I don't have the exact name of each file (names change weekly so I have to open them using glob).
When I try to open files, the ones with ascii encoding hace error: 'UnicodeDecodeError: utf-8 codec can't decode byte.....'
I have read about this and I have tried with encoding latin-1, changing files extension, etc but I couldn't Solve it.

How can I open those files using glob without error or how can I change the encoding of all files from a folder?

Thanks

How can I open those files using glob without error or how can I change the encoding of all files from a folder?

Comment: Can you share the code used ?

Comment: Yes, sorry! Here Is an example of one of the files: file1 = pd.read_csv(glob.glob('*_file1.csv')[0])

Comment: ASCII is a subset of UTF-8, so the "ASCII" files are not encoded in ASCII; otherwise, UTF-8 will decode both pure ASCII as well as UTF-8 files.  You'll have to determine what the encoding actually is.

Comment: It could verified they have ANSI encoding. I need to change them from ANSI to utf-8

Comment: It may well be that they are ANSI-encoding, but you need to make sure what ANSI-encoding it is. If it is Windows-ANSI, there are some 10+ variants. Your problem is that the same byte above 0x7F is valid in the document, but will produce different results in UTF8, as it is different in each codepage.   Example: `0xD8` is `Ø` in Windows 1252 (western europe), but `Ř` in Windows 1250 (eastern europe). Same byte, different UTF8 result.  Opening in wrong codepage will not produce errors in output, but may result in [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake)

Comment: I hace different ANSI encoding depending ok the file. Suppossing it Is 1252 for all CSV files, how could I change it yo utf-8?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Couldn't Solve it. Had to modify encoding mannually